# Find regular expression for the similar string

Tags: regex

```
$string ='<p>Jane has:&nbsp;{num1} times&nbsp;<img alt="" src="/ckfinder/userfiles/images/shapes/button4.jpg" style="height:59px; width:60px" /></p>

<p>Her Father gives her:&nbsp;{num2} times&nbsp;<img alt="" src="/ckfinder/userfiles/images/shapes/button4.jpg" style="height:59px; width:60px" /></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Total No of Buttons She Have: ans</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
';
```

In this string I want these two lines to be extracted:

1. Jane has: {num1} times
2. Her Father gives her: {num2} times

Also, I need to extract the string which doesn't mach the two strings.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Maybe something like `.*\{num\d+\}.*`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this . it worked perfectly in python :)

```
re.findall(r'[\w :]+[\{][a-z]{3}[0-9]*[\}][\w ]*',st)
```

Comment: just replace `st` with `string`